# How to know that queue is removed?

Tags: c#, rabbitmq

I create a queue:

```
        _channel = rmqConnection.CreateModel();
        _channel.QueueDeclare("myqueue", false, false, false, null);
        _channel.BasicAcks += _channel_BasicAcks;
        _channel.BasicNacks += _channel_BasicNacks;
        _channel.BasicRecoverOk += _channel_BasicRecoverOk;
        _channel.BasicReturn += _channel_BasicReturn;
        _channel.CallbackException += _channel_CallbackException;
        _channel.FlowControl += _channel_FlowControl;
        _channel.ModelShutdown += _channel_ModelShutdown;
```

and then i want to subscribe on event when (and if) queue will remove.
So, when i manual remove a queue for test this: i can not handle event.

How can i handle event about queue remove\destroy?

P.S. add some new code:

```
        var consumer = new EventingBasicConsumer(_channel);
        consumer.Received += OnMessageRecieved;
        consumer.ConsumerCancelled += Consumer_ConsumerCancelled;
        consumer.Registered += Consumer_Registered;
        consumer.Shutdown += Consumer_Shutdown;
        consumer.Unregistered += Consumer_Unregistered;
        _channel.BasicConsume(SharebleConst.RmqQueueName, false, consumer);
```

When queue created, `Consumer_Registered` rises.
When i remove queue, `Consumer_ConsumerCancelled` rises

Comment: Just curious: what do you need this for?

Comment: Where is being queue destroyed ?

Comment: @Rainman, i remove it manual from administration panel. But, at production this queue removed too (not manual.of cource)

Comment: why the queue is removed in production? typically you don't need to remove them.

Answer (score 1):

There is **not** a way to get notified if a queue is deleted.

You could implement your own tool to do that, using a notification exchange and send a message each time you create or destroy a queue.

or in genral, send changing status messages